# "Bake" Array and Curve modifer animation for GLTF export?

Tags: animation, modifiers, keyframes, gltf

I'm having a bit of an issue optimizing my model for export to GLTF. Specifically, since GLTF does not allow modifiers, and any animations need to consist of basically pure keyframes. This causes an issue, most easily explained with these two gifs:

| In Blender | In GLTF Viewer |
| --- | --- |
| [image: In Blender1] | [image: In GLTF] |

Here is my modifier setup on the "power beads":

[image: Blender Screenshot of Modifers]

The issue, as I understand it, is that when the modifiers get applied, their path-following goes away.

So, is there any way to convert this specific animation from "modifier-driven" to something that works with pure keyframes or is otherwise GLTF compatible? Is there a completely different approach that would serve me better here? I want to animate power flowing from point to point, and have the ability to control the speed and direction of the animation in JS (which, for example, three.js can do)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. I figured it out, but the process is a bit of a pain. Here's how I did it:

1. Create single sphere and curve. Use `Ctrl+P` and `Follow Path` to parent the sphere to the curve.
2. Select the sphere, and use the `Object` menu to `Clear Origin`. The sphere should jump to the start of the curve.
3. Fiddle with the `Follow Path` settings in the curve's properties to get a speed you like.
4. Once satisfied with the animation, select the sphere, go to `Object`, then `Animate` and `Bake Action`. Make sure to input how many frames and check the `Visual Keying` box.
5. With the baked animation, the sphere jumps somewhere else so you need to clear the parent: `Clear Parent` on the right-click menu of the object.
6. Go into `Animation`, and make sure you're looking at the `Dope Sheet`. With the object selected, duplicate it in the 3d viewport, and then offset the duplicates of the keyframes by however many frames you want.
7. Repeat this process until your entire loop is seamless. You'll need duplicates going both forwards and backwards on the timeline.
8. Select all the duplicates and delete all keyframes that are outside of the looping portion. This is important for GLTF, because otherwise it will start at the first keyframe regardless of where your `Start` is set and go to the last keyframe regardless of `End` frame.
9. Group the animation actions. Change from Dope Sheet to the Non-Linear editor, and then for each object, click the `Push Down` button in the bright orange section. A new, gray line will appear with a star. Name this something--all elements such named with the same name will be grouped as a single animation in the final GLTF file after export.

Comment: Thanks for this, finally a solution that works. Any chance you also figured out how to apply a curve modifier in the gltf? (Think conveyor belt where blocks curve around the ends)

Comment: This deserves an addon or something. I'm trying to animate a tank track and although I totally understand this process works, I'm going to lose my mind have to repeat this 200 times.